# Can't find my form in PowerApps, but it can be accessed from link in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I'm currently working on a registration form for a conference. I made a form for the SharePoint list using the PowerApps link in SharePoint (web). I published the form, and now I can't find it on the PowerApps site when I go to open applications for editing. I can edit the form using the edit link in my SharePoint list, but I'm unable to find it anywhere on the PowerApps website... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the "Customize forms" option or "Create an App"?
If you used the former, then your app will not be listed if you try accessing it through the Powerapps site or Mobile App.
There is a difference between these two. Customize form is specific to the list while create an app creates a new app for you on powerapps using the Sharepoint list as the datasource

Comment: I did use the "Customize forms" link from the sharepoint list directly.. Thank you for time!